# O que é compreensão de lista? Estrutura de controle? Loop?

Tags: loop, terminologia, independente-de-linguagem

Algumas linguagens possuem uma forma de criar outras listas sem precisar de funções de alta ordem como map e filter. Essa forma é chamada de compreensão de lista, ou *list comprehension*. É comum de ver compreensões de lista até em linguagens funcionais, onde map e filter são mais comuns, como Haskell, Erlang e Elixir.

Alguns exemplos:

```
Python> [fruit for fruit in ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'] if 'a' in fruit]
['apple', 'banana']

Elixir> for n <- 0..5, rem(n, 3) == 0, do: n * n
[0, 9]

C#> from number in Enumerable.Range(0, 3) select 2 * number;
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Independente da linguagem, o que é compreensão de lista? É considerado uma estrutura de controle como o `for`? E por fim, compreensão de lista é um loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compreensões de lista nada mais são que um açúcar sintático para a construção de listas, muitas vezes a partir de outra lista ou através de alguma regra bem definida.

Essas construções foram inspiradas na [notação para construção de conjuntos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) da Matemática e são extremamente comuns em linguagens funcionais (que também advém de fortes fundamentos Matemáticos).

É importante ressaltar que as *list comprehensions* são formas diferentes de *manipular* listas, se comparados aos tradicionais laços de repetição (como o `for`) ou funções de ordem superior, tais como `map`, `filter`, etc.

Apesar dessa diferença na forma de se manipular, internamente, o compilador provavelmente irá gerar estruturas muito similares para os três padrões citados acima, já que todos eles baseiam-se na iteração sobre elementos de uma lista.

Mas é claro que algumas características podem variar de linguagem para linguagem. [Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension), por exemplo, trata as listas criadas com *list comprehensions* de forma *lazy* (assim como quase tudo na linguagem). Mas Python, por exemplo, que também tem [esse recurso](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), trata-as de maneira *eager*, de modo que também fornece as chamadas [*generators expresions*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), que operam sob o comportamento preguiçoso.

> É considerado uma estrutura de controle como o `for`? E por fim, compreensão de lista é um loop?

A nível de linguagem, eu não diria que compreensões de lista são um `for`, já que o `for` também é um recurso sintático das linguagens que o implementam.

Mas no fundo, padrões que "repetem" algo na programação sempre terão uma semelhança interna.

Compreensões de lista podem, sim, ser vistas como um "*loop*" de expressões, já que iteram sobre uma lista. Veja, por exemplo, este caso, em Haskell:

```hs
Prelude> mult2 = (*) 2

Prelude> [mult2 i | i <- [1, 2, 3]]
[2, 4, 6]
```

Está, basicamente, passando por cada elemento da lista original, `[1, 2, 3]` e aplicando a função `mult2`, de modo que gera a lista `[2, 4, 6]`.

Perceba que, além da diferença sintática, não há muita diferença em se fazer assim:

```hs
Prelude> mult2 = (*) 2

Prelude> fmap mult2 [1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 6]
```

Que utiliza a função `fmap` para mapear os elementos da lista, aplicando-os numa função. Repare que o resultado é o mesmo.

Ambos exemplos podem ser vistos como *loops* e, de fato, são implementados internamente com algum mecanismo de repetição.

As compreensões de lista são, portanto, um meio mais "declarativo" de se repetir coisas. É claro que uma linguagem funcional prefere abordagens mais orientadas à expressões do que a tradicional abordagem imperativa, marcada pelo clássico `for`. Faz sentido do ponto de vista semântico da linguagem.

Comment: Na primeira linha já ganhou o meu voto de utilidade. Terminei de ler e valeu o upvote.

Comment: Eu votei, pois essa frase *"Compreensões de lista nada mais são que um açúcar sintático para a construção de listas"*  responde cirurgicamente a pergunta.  Até quem está começando a programar compreende a mensagem.